# How to remove an array element using a specific value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Suppose I have an array structured like this:

```
{ q1: true, q2: false, q3: false, q4: true, q5:true }
```

Is there a way to remove all the elements that has "false" for a value in AngularJS?

I tried using splice() by getting the index number, with no luck. Now I'm looking for a way where I don't have to use a specific index number.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple JavaScript approach

```js
var r = {
  q1: true,
  q2: false,
  q3: false,
  q4: true,
  q5: true
};

for (a in r) {
  if (!r[a]) {
    delete r[a]
  }
}

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you. It works great. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an array, this is an object. You can use this function to remove every key whose value is falsy with:

```
angular.forEach(obj, function (val, key) {
  if (!val) {
    delete obj[key];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You supplied an object, not an array. [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) works with arrays, not objects.

To *filter out* unwanted values from an array, you should use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
[true, false, false, true, true].filter(function(el){ return el; });
// returns [true, true, true]
```